# Moving from coderush to resharper

Tags: resharper, coderush

I am about to make the switch to resharper from coderush after using it for 30 days and have some questions I would like to see if I can get some help on.

1: Can you change the resharper code colors? I tend to prefer dark themes so I would like to be able to migrate to a dark theme once the change is complete.

2: Do any other addin provide the member icon paint functionality of Coderush? It is the only feature that I do actually miss as it is handy for scanning. I don't mind paying for the functionality if it works.

EDIT: Found out how to change syntax colors.

Comment: Resharper has a 30 day trial, why not see for yourself?

Comment: I did try the 30 day trial, which has now run out. I never bothered to check the color as it was only a nice to have. It seems you can though. The member icon is not in resharper, which is why I asked for other addons.

Comment: Sorry thought you meant you'd tried CodeRush for 30 days. With R# you can change the code colours.

Comment: Ah ok, No I have coderush a long time but resharper seems much better. It grooves more with how I write code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct replacement of "paint member icons" in ReSharper.

I suggest that you use the [File Structure](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Windows__File_Structure_Window.html) window instead, with "Track caret in editor" and/or "Automatically scroll to source" options on to synchronize between focus in File Structure and the caret in the text editor.

As to other VS plug-ins, to my knowledge there aren't any prominent plug-ins that have that - neither VS10x CodeMap nor Productivity Power Tools provide anything similar.

Comment: Cheers, It is not a big lose but it was a nice feature to have.

Answer (score 0):

> 1: Can you change the resharper code colors? I tend to prefer dark
>   themes so I would like to be able to migrate to a dark theme once the
>   change is complete.

As well as being able to change Resharper colours (In Tools->Options->Fonts and Colours, look for the "Resharper *" related options), R# supports Visual Studio light and dark themes:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Managing_Color_Themes.html